# Uncaught TypeError: $(...). is not a function... flagged after upgrade to PHP7.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slimbox

I upgraded my test server environment from PHP 5.x to 7.0.  This has resulted in quite a few changes to the base code (mysql --> mysqli, etc), but this error has me running in circles.  I am using the stock slimbox2 lightbox jQuery alternative.  After the upgraded PHP modules, and dsorted out most of the issues, the slimbox no longer worked, and flagged with this error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slimbox is not a function
  If I drill down a bit, the following is the location the error is coming from (straight from slimbox2.js.. v2.05):

```
if (!/android|iphone|ipod|series60|symbian|windows ce|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
jQuery(function($) {
    $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({/* Put custom options here */}, null, function(el) {
        return (this == el) || ((this.rel.length > 8) && (this.rel == el.rel));
    });
});
```

Other posts seems to circle in on this error being a conflict between JQuery / Prototype / etc.

The function is defined in slimbox2.js and they all appear to be wrapped in JQuery to ensure the right bits are being pulled.

Thanks for any ideas of help you can provide!

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with slimbox/JS, excepting as what conflicting JavaScript the PHP program may generate. One of the client-side dependencies (or URLs of such, etc.) changed - perhaps one of the files failed to be downloaded?

Comment: Have you imported jQuery? Maybe the libraries are being imported in the wrong order?

Comment: You could try to press F12 in the browser and check out the network tab for any files that fail to load. Filter by js files and see what is loaded. jQuery should be loaded somewhere but maybe it is loaded after you tried to use it instead of before.

Comment: All, I confirmed that all expected files are loading per the network tab, this includes jquery. However, the issue persists. JQuery is the loaded multiple times as different pages load, and a small ajax script also loads.  These coexisted happily before tho.

Comment: I tried the 'example' that comes with the slimbox 2 code.  it does not work either, but also does not flag any errors.  This points me more towards a server configuration issue, as it works fine on the production machine (which is not running kubuntu 16.04 yet).

Comment: This issue is a configuration problem on my development system.  The code works just fine on the production server.

Comment: Turns out the issue was buried somewhere in a package that was not properly installed.  I unloaded the webserver and php packages and put them back again, resoling the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was buried somewhere in a package that was not properly installed. I unloaded the webserver and php packages and put them back again, resoling the issue.